# twitter API - is search api will give exact word only even without double quoted the word?

Tags: php, twitter

i was thinking that twitter search API will give us non exact word, like: **watch** will give, watched, watching, and watchs too.

But after several experiment i didnt catch any result which containing watched/watching/watchs without **watch** there.

if i search **"watch"** (with double quote) i'm sure that API will not given me watched/watchs/watching without contain any **watch** in the result. So thats why i was thinking that without give double quote on **watch**, i will found any word contain watch like watched/watchs/watching.

if using **watch** will only give exact word watch, why i found :

- watch.
- watch:
- "watch"
- watch!!!

So,, my question :  *is search api will give exact word only **even** without double quoted the word?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no way to fuzzy search on twitter. No wildcards, no vague search.

Everything is explained here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Space are only here to search something containing both “watch” and “now”. This is the default operator. But you can not search for "watch" with anything trailing.

One other way would be to use the OR operator. But you have to precise everything:

```
watch OR watching OR watches OR watched
```

But I think it's not what you really want. So answer is no :/

Comment: sorry, for my late accept. your answer is usefull for me to make sure that the answer is NO. thank you very much